# Mavericks Some System Preferences Panes won't open

Tags: macos, system-settings

I first noticed there, but many system preferences similar panels won't open anymore. VPN Authentication Settings; Security & Privacy > Advanced; iCloud > Manager or Options; Date & Time > Customize Voice...

I click, the button responds visually but nothing happens. It's almost as if they were decorative buttons now.

While few others do open: Energy Saver > Schedule; Keyboard > Modifier Keys...

The weirdest part is that it's something wrong with my user. If I try from any other user, they work.

There's a [big thread on apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23522953#23522953) about this already, but I'm still reading through all of it... Nothing I could see in the first page there helped me as well (specially comments from *macjack*).

This is what I see on the console:

```
2013-11-15 7:24:37.978 PM System Preferences[96729]: *** Assertion failure in -[NSSecureColor initWithColor:], /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46/NSSecureColor.m:32
2013-11-15 7:24:37.979 PM System Preferences[96729]: -[NSRemoteView viewDidMoveToWindow] caught non-fatal NSInternalInconsistencyException 'unable to convert NSNamedColorSpace System controlColor to Device RGB colorspace' with backtrace (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8aaa241c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff83757e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8aaa21f8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e0e6c61 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
    4   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6bd65c -[NSSecureColor initWithColor:] + 724
    5   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6bd36f +[NSSecureColor secureColorWithColor:] + 48
    6   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e0cfb -[NSRemoteView sendFontSmoothingBackgroundColorToService:] + 40
    7   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e1bf5 -[NSRemoteView viewDidMoveToWindow] + 197
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c30a1d0 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2899
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c307804 -[NSView addSubview:] + 364
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c31b953 -[NSFrameView addSubview:] + 45
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c329cb5 -[NSWindow setContentView:] + 511
    12  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e7868 rendezvousPanel + 895
    13  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e6f3f -[NSRemoteView beginSheet:modalForWindow:size:isCritical:styleMask:] + 420
    14  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e7eea -[NSRemoteView beginDeferredSheet:] + 209
    15  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e8098 -[NSRemoteView beginDeferredSheets] + 283
    16  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6ecca2 __85-[NSRemoteViewMarshal beginSheet:modalForWindow:size:isCritical:styleMask:withReply:]_block_invoke + 83
    17  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6f0892 __deferBlockOntoMainThread_block_invoke_3 + 441
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9d37cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9c4ee5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9c4c6e __CFRunLoopRun + 1982
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9c4275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    22  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84223f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84223cb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
    24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84223abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2f328e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2f28db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2e69cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2d1803 NSApplicationMain + 940
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff896d85fd start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
timestamp: 19:24:37.979 Friday 15 November 2013
process/thread/queue: System Preferences (96729) / 0x7fff72caa310 / com.apple.main-thread
code: line 607 of /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46/ViewBridgeUtilities.m in logCaughtException
domain: exceptions

2013-11-15 7:24:37.980 PM System Preferences[96729]: -[NSRemoteView beginDeferredSheets] caught non-fatal NSInternalInconsistencyException 'unable to convert NSNamedColorSpace System controlColor to Device RGB colorspace' with backtrace (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8aaa241c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff83757e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8aaa21f8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e0e6c61 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
    4   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6bd65c -[NSSecureColor initWithColor:] + 724
    5   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6bd36f +[NSSecureColor secureColorWithColor:] + 48
    6   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e0cfb -[NSRemoteView sendFontSmoothingBackgroundColorToService:] + 40
    7   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e1bf5 -[NSRemoteView viewDidMoveToWindow] + 197
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c30a1d0 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2899
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c307804 -[NSView addSubview:] + 364
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c31b953 -[NSFrameView addSubview:] + 45
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c329cb5 -[NSWindow setContentView:] + 511
    12  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e7868 rendezvousPanel + 895
    13  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e6f3f -[NSRemoteView beginSheet:modalForWindow:size:isCritical:styleMask:] + 420
    14  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e7eea -[NSRemoteView beginDeferredSheet:] + 209
    15  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6e8098 -[NSRemoteView beginDeferredSheets] + 283
    16  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6ecca2 __85-[NSRemoteViewMarshal beginSheet:modalForWindow:size:isCritical:styleMask:withReply:]_block_invoke + 83
    17  ViewBridge                          0x00007fff8e6f0892 __deferBlockOntoMainThread_block_invoke_3 + 441
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9d37cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9c4ee5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9c4c6e __CFRunLoopRun + 1982
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a9c4275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    22  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84223f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84223cb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
    24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff84223abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2f328e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2f28db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2e69cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c2d1803 NSApplicationMain + 940
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff896d85fd start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
timestamp: 19:24:37.980 Friday 15 November 2013
process/thread/queue: System Preferences (96729) / 0x7fff72caa310 / com.apple.main-thread
code: line 607 of /SourceCache/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-46/ViewBridgeUtilities.m in logCaughtException
domain: exceptions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread I linked had [the answer](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23727047#23727047)!

In a Terminal window:

> ```
> defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSUseLeopardWindowValues YES
> defaults write com.apple.Safari NSUseLeopardWindowValues NO
> killall SystemUIServer
> ```